# Node JS bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am creating promises with node JS. But i have the idea that i still have a callback hell going on...

That is because i need results from my first callback, in the third callback.

I already tried it with bluebird, but i have some confusion about this.

Can anyone give me some sample code how i can write this out nicely?
See the following example:
https://gist.github.com/ermst4r/8b29bf8b63d74f639521e04c4481dabb

Comment: Code that is required to understand and answer your question MUST be pasted into your question itself and then formatted appropriately.  You may also provide external link references, but they cannot be the primary means by which one understands your question.  This is because external references tend to get changed or disappear over time, rendering the original question useless as a long term reference (which is one of stack overflow's goals).

Comment: Also, please pick a more relevant title that describes the actual problem you're asking about.  Your title is incredibly generic.

Answer (score 1):

Use async / await to avoid nested promises.

You could refactor your code to something like this

```
async function doSomething(){
    try {
        const user = await UserProfileMatch.getNewUser(item.fk_user_id)
        await ActiveAuctionProfile.closeActiveAuctionProfile(item.aap_id)

        if(user.length  > 0 ) {
            const is_active = await ActiveAuctionProfile.isProfileActive(user[0].profile_id)

            const number_of_profiles = await = UserProfileMatch.countActiveProfilesForUser(item.fk_user_id)

            if(is_active.result === 0 && number_of_profiles < config.settings.lovingbids_start_profile) {

                await UserProfileMatch.updateProfileMatch(item.fk_user_id, user[0].profile_id,1,false)

                await ActiveAuctionProfile.createNewActiveProfile({
                    fk_auction_profile_id:user[0].profile_id,
                    start_date:moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") ,
                    expire_date:moment().add(config.settings.increment_settings,'seconds').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                })

                ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id);
                page++;
                next();

            } else {
                console.log("exists");
                ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id);
                page++;
                next();
            }

        } else {
            console.log("niet");
            page++;
            next();
        }

    }catch(err){
       console.log("One of the promises failed:", err)
    }
}
```

Note that we declare the wrapping function with `async` and that instead of nesting the callbacks, we use await to tell the async function to wait for this function to finish before running the next line of code.

Also note that all the await functions are wrapped in a try / catch block to catch any errors. This is instead of using the `.catch()` notation.

Read more about async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't debug but something along these lines should give you a refactored code using promises correctly.

```
UserProfileMatch.getNewUser(item.fk_user_id)
                .then(user => ActiveAuctionProfile.closeActiveAuctionProfile(item.aap_id))
                .then(() => user.length  > 0 ? ActiveAuctionProfile.isProfileActive(user[0].profile_id)
                                             : (console.log("niet"), page++, next()))
                .then(is_active => [UserProfileMatch.countActiveProfilesForUser(item.fk_user_id), is_active.result])
                .then(([number_of_profiles,n]) => n === 0 &&
                                                  number_of_profiles < config.settings.lovingbids_start_profile ? UserProfileMatch.updateProfileMatch(item.fk_user_id, user[0].profile_id,1,false))
                                                                                                                : (console.log("exists"),
                                                                                                                   ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id),
                                                                                                                   page++,
                                                                                                                   next());
                .then(() => ActiveAuctionProfile.createNewActiveProfile({ fk_auction_profile_id: user[0].profile_id,
                                                                          start_date           : moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") ,
                                                                          expire_date          : moment().add(config.settings.increment_settings,'seconds').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                                                                        })
                .then(() => (ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id), page++, next()));
```

Please note that at the 3rd `then` stage i returned an array like

```
[UserProfileMatch.countActiveProfilesForUser(item.fk_user_id), is_active.result]
```

which carries the `is_active.result` to the next `then` stage, at where we collect it as `n` through array destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Nice thanks all for your feedback. I read about `async` and `async.series` seems to be the best way for me. It keeps my code structured. See ....

```
                            var get_user;
                            var user_active;
                            var user_profile;
                            async.series([

                                // check for the new user
                                function checkForNewUser(callback)
                                {
                                    UserProfileMatch.getNewUser(item.fk_user_id).then(function (user) {
                                        get_user = user;
                                        callback(null,user);

                                    });
                                },
                                // close the profile
                                function closeProfile(callback)
                                {
                                    ActiveAuctionProfile.closeActiveAuctionProfile(item.aap_id).then(function () {
                                        if (get_user.length > 0) {
                                            ActiveAuctionProfile.isProfileActive(get_user[0].profile_id).then(function (is_active) {
                                                user_active = is_active.result;
                                                callback(null,user_active);
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            callback(null,false);
                                        }

                                    });

                                },

                                // count the active profiles
                                function countActiveProfiles (callback) {

                                    UserProfileMatch.countActiveProfilesForUser(item.fk_user_id).then(function (number_of_profiles) {
                                        user_profile = number_of_profiles;
                                        callback(null,user_profile);
                                    });
                                },

                                // decide when we want to create an user
                                function determineCreation(callback) {

                                    if(user_active === 0 && user_active === 0) {
                                        UserProfileMatch.updateProfileMatch(item.fk_user_id, get_user[0].profile_id, 1, false).then(function () {
                                            ActiveAuctionProfile.createNewActiveProfile({
                                                fk_auction_profile_id: get_user[0].profile_id,
                                                start_date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                                                expire_date: moment().add(config.settings.increment_settings, 'seconds').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
                                            }).then(function () {
                                                ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id);
                                                callback(null,true);
                                            });

                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        ExpireProfileRegister.removeExpireResult(item.id);
                                        callback(null,true);
                                    }
                                }

                            ], function(err,res) {
                                // after done, go to the next page
                                page++;
                                next();
                            });
```

Comment: Love that indentation.